# Colab tflite-model-maker cant install

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, tensor, tflite

I am trying to install tflite-model-maker on colab but if i try this
`!pip install -q tflite-model-maker`
installing is taking so much time and disk will full.
If i try this
`!pip install -q --use-deprecated=legacy-resolver tflite-model-maker`
I am getting this error

`ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tflite-support>=0.4.2 (from tflite-model-maker) (from versions: 0.1.0a0.dev3, 0.1.0a0.dev4, 0.1.0a0.dev5, 0.1.0a0, 0.1.0a1)`

`ERROR: No matching distribution found for tflite-support>=0.4.2 (from tflite-model-maker)`

And i can not import tflite-model-maker.
Using python 3.10 on colab. I try to change it from change alternatives but when i try to install packages with pip i am getting root user warning

Answer (score 0):

I suggested to use virtual environment in the [tensorflow forum](https://discuss.tensorflow.org/t/tflite-model-maker-installation/16577/21?u=funnypig).

You can work in colab from terminal, possibly you can apply virtual env for notebook also, but that wasn't my need.

```
python3.8 -m virtualenv venv
virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3.8 liteenv
source liteenv/bin/activate
pip install --upgrade pip==20.1.1
pip install tensorflow==2.8.0
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/examples
cd examples/tensorflow_examples/lite/model_maker/pip_package
pip3 install -e .

// fix some dependencies. may differ for you 
pip3 install protobuf==3.20.0 numpy==1.20.3
```